# Renders get pixelated when viewed up close

Tags: rendering, image

I have been using blender for about a year now and have only just started to notice that all my pictures are actually not that HD. If you zoom in on a render just once, you can see each individual pixel colour. I don't know if this this is a big or if it is something I can do or even if this happens to everyone.
Please help as its really bugging me now.

Here is an example of a render that is a bit pixelated:

Save the picture and open it in fullscreen and zoom in just a bit.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image you uploaded has the dimensions of `960 x 540`. This is half HD. Most likely the problem is that your render scale is set to 50%. This means that the actual render size will be 50% of the specified render size.

To fix the problem. Set the scale to 100%, than your renders will actually be full HD

[image]